# Relevant questions getting closed due to the identity of the asker

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

It appears to have happened to a couple of my questions specifically on Network Engineering.

I'd be asking about how things work in the telecom world (and since the telephony and telecom proposals were too specific to have their own SE, Network Engineering seems quite close enough, even having the *telephony* tag), yet these questions would be closed, basically, solely on the determination that *I'm an end user*.

- https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22479/why-911-calls-over-wcdma-fail-right-away-when-the-rest-just-hang  (The question basically asks whether it's the network or the mobile-equipment that's "supposed" to drop/hangup the 911 calls.)

Is this an OK thing to do?

How is the user's identity really relevant here, to the question as above?

What kind of additional "professional" information is supposed to be provided for such a higher-level question?!

At neighbouring ServerFault, we do have an assumption that questions shall relate to servers used in professional capacity, too, but I can't really see someone's questions being closed solely because they're obviously a hobby end user, yet are asking an interesting higher-level question as it relates to the servers.

Comment: Before asking on a Stack Exchange site, it's generally a good idea to familiarize with the site's scope by reading their "/help/on-topic" and "/help/how-to-ask" pages. Did you? Because it seems the close reason given is pretty clear, and has nothing to do with the "identity of the user asking the question", but completely with the site's scope.

Answer (score 3):

During the creation phase of a site the users involved get to choose what is on and off topic. Different sites form around different communities.

Sometimes there's specific sites for amateurs vs professionals e.g. [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) vs [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)

That's just an effect of how the communities that formed those sites formed them.

In your case the community formed around professional network engineers and they decided not to allow your kind of question. I'm afraid that's up to that community to do that.

The kind of information they might want is. What kind of network infrastructure does the network have? Who made it? How does it connect together? What protocols does it use? None of this is known to you as an end user but if you did know it, it might enable that community to say, protocol XXX works like that on YYY manufacturers kit, you need to upgrade it to version ZZZ to fix it. Such an answer would not be much use to you anyway as you don't own that part of the infrastructure.

Do you think your question might be on topic on the [Android Enthusiasts site](https://android.stackexchange.com/) since it seems to be about an Android phone? Check their [help centre](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first before you ask.